# White glitches randomly appears on my screen

Tags: gnome, graphics, 19.10

This only happens on my old laptop, a HP Pavilion DV7 6180SL. I seldom use it, but when I need to use it I'd still like to avoid the problem :)

Since a few ubuntu releases there is something strange that happens from time to time, which is some graphic glitches (usually white) on some icons, or part of applications. It's pretty annoying and sometimes I have to reboot... Today I have updated to ubuntu 19.10 and still there is the same problem.

Here is a photo of the problem. Sorry for the horrible quality but still you can see the issue
[image]

**Edit: system specs:**
Intel Core i5
Ram 4 GB (upgraded to 8)
AMD Radeon HD 6770M

This time only I did an upgrade from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Ubuntu 19.04 was a fresh install, already having the same problem.

**Edit 2**
I have also noticed that when this happens on a web page, the glitch scrolls together with the web page O_o

Comment: You probably should add system information, in particular about the graphical card. Did you do an update or a fresh install? An update may take over the old driver, while a fresh install will install default drivers.

Comment: you're right, I've added some informations

Comment: Important to know it is Radeon. Unfortunately, I cannot help. If it were Intel, I would have suggested to try the Xorg driver rather than the nomodeset (=kernel) driver. Here, only Xorg drivers apply. Still, you could try different drivers.

Comment: @ToX 82 Please eliminate the chance of a hardware problem by booting from your LiveUSb and running from it for a while.

Comment: @vanadium it just came to my mind that this laptop has an hybrid graphic card, with an intel hd 3000. Could you tell me more about the Xorg driver?